# Getting a number of integers which are more than some value using Aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, list, aggregate

I have a task to find a number of integers which are more than some specified value using `Aggregate`. For example, there is a list of integers

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
```

On this list I need to find the number of elements of this list which are more than `250`. There should be `3` of them, but I need to use `Aggregate` there somehow to find this number.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Can you please show existing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Count`, which is designed for counting:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 List<int> list = new List<int>() { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };

 ...

 int result = list.Count(item => item > 250);
```

If you insist on `Aggregate`:

```
 int result = list.Aggregate(0, (s, a) => a > 250 ? s + 1 : s);
```

Comment: Tnanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I agree that using Count is much more simplier than Aggregate in this case, but I have such a strange task there..